# Adding lines into a Json file generated in R

Tags: json, r

I want to generate a JSON file in R. For example:

```
forJson <- data.frame(names = c("John", "Mary", "Pat", "Rick"), values = 3:6)
library("jsonlite")
toJson <- toJSON(forJson, pretty = TRUE)
toJson
```

However, I am required to add some info to this file. At the end it should look like this:

```
[
 "CaseID": 12345,
 "graph": "Name-of-the-graph",
 "Items":[{

  {
    "names": "John",
    "values": 3
  },
  {
    "names": "Mary",
    "values": 4
  },
  {
    "names": "Pat",
    "values": 5
  },
  {
    "names": "Rick",
    "values": 6
  }]
]
```

I am not experienced with JSON at all. It feels like my current values for the table should be inside an object called "Items". And then I have to have 2 pieces of metainformation - CaseID and graph name - on the top.
Any advice how I could add such lines or generate them to begin with using toJSON?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Put your data in a list, and then convert it to JSON

```
forJson <- list(CaseID = 1234, graph = "name-of-the-graph", Items = forJson)
toJSON(forJson, pretty = T)
# 
# {
#   "CaseID": [1234],
#   "graph": ["name-of-the-graph"],
#   "Items": [
#       {
#           "names": "John",
#           "values": 3
#       },
#       {
#           "names": "Mary",
#           "values": 4
#       },
#       {
#           "names": "Pat",
#           "values": 5
#       },
#       {
#           "names": "Rick",
#           "values": 6
#       }
#       ]
# }
```

A slight variation is to have a `data.frame` inside a `list` column of your overall `data.frame`

```
forJson <- data.frame(CaseID = 1234, graph = "name_of_graph")
forJson$Items <- list(data.frame(names = c("John", "Mary", "Pat", "Rick"), 
                                values = 3:6))

toJSON(forJson, pretty = T)

# [
#   {
#       "CaseID": 1234,
#       "graph": "name_of_graph",
#       "Items": [
#           {
#               "names": "John",
#               "values": 3
#           },
#           {
#               "names": "Mary",
#               "values": 4
#           },
#           {
#               "names": "Pat",
#               "values": 5
#           },
#           {
#               "names": "Rick",
#               "values": 6
#           }
#           ]
#   }
#   ]
```

---

The easy way to work out the R structure you need is to work backwards from the JSON by reading it in using `fromJSON()`, which will automatically give you the R structure

```
js <- '{
      "CaseID": 1234,
      "graph": "name_of_graph",
      "Items": [
          {
              "names": "John",
              "values": 3
          },
          {
              "names": "Mary",
              "values": 4
          },
          {
              "names": "Pat",
              "values": 5
          },
          {
              "names": "Rick",
              "values": 6
          }
          ]
  }'

lst <- jsonlite::fromJSON(js)
lst
$CaseID
[1] 1234

$graph
[1] "name_of_graph"

$Items
  names values
1  John      3
2  Mary      4
3   Pat      5
4  Rick      6
```

However, note that even though `fromJSON()` read in the values for `CaseID` and `graph` as single elements, the `toJSON()` automatically makes them into array elements (but in reality I can't see this being a problem).

```
toJSON(lst, pretty = T)
{
  "CaseID": [1234],
  "graph": ["name_of_graph"],
  "Items": [
    {
      "names": "John",
      "values": 3
    },
    ... etc
```

Comment: @user3245256 You're welcome. I wasn't sure the exact format you wanted so gave you the two options. Note the subtle difference where the first has an array for each object, and the second has objects against `CaseID` and `graph`, and an array against `Items`

Comment: REgarding the last solution: any way to get rid of the very first and very last [ and ]?

Comment: In the second solution everything is exactly what I was asked for. But everything is wrapped in [] in addition to {} - any way to get rid of that?

Comment: @user3245256 please see my update for an explanation of how to get the structure you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's  VERY helpful!

Comment: @user3245256. No problem. If this answers your question you should 'accept' it by pressing the 'tick' under the voting arrows